# Filter list using dynamic whole word matching regex in dart

Tags: regex, list, flutter, filter, where-clause

I'm filtering list like this but i think there should be better approach to filter list inside where bloc it is not allowing me to declare variable. is there any other way to achieve the same

```
var cc = contactsAll
          .where(
            (i) =>
                regularExpression(i.displayName, 'dev') ||
                regularExpression(i.displayName, 'soft') ||
                regularExpression(i.displayName, 'angular') ||
                regularExpression(i.displayName, 'java') 
          )
          .toList();
```

my expression filter function

```
  bool regularExpression(String stringg, String search) {
    RegExp exp = new RegExp(
      "\\b" + search + "\\b",
      caseSensitive: false,
    );
    return exp.hasMatch(stringg);
  }
```

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may build the pattern dynamically:

```
var keys = ['dev', 'soft', 'angular', 'java'];
var regex = new RegExp("\\b(?:${keys.join('|')})\\b", caseSensitive: false);
var contactsAll = ['No match', 'I like java', 'I like javascript'];
var cc = contactsAll.where( (i) => regex.hasMatch(i) ).toList();
print(cc); // => [I like java]
```

The regex will look like `\b(?:dev|soft|angular|java)\b` and will match any of the keywords inside the [non-capturing group](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3512471/what-is-a-non-capturing-group-in-regular-expressions) as a whole word due to the `\b` [word boundaries](https://www.regular-expressions.info/wordboundaries.html). See the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/Gjs56E/1).

If the `keys` can contain special characters, but you still need a whole word search, you need to escape all special characters and use either *unambiguous boundaries*

```
var regex = new RegExp("(?:^|\\W)(?:${keys.map((val) => val.replaceAll(new RegExp(r'[-\/\\^$*+?.()|[\]{}]'), r'\\$&')).join('|')})(?!\\w)", caseSensitive: false);
```

This results in a `(?:^|\W)(?:dev|soft|angular|java)(?!\w)` pattern ([see demo](https://regex101.com/r/Gjs56E/2)) where `(?:^|\W)` matches start of string or a non-word char and `(?!\w)` requires the absense of a word char immediately to the right of the current location.

The `.map((val) => val.replaceAll(new RegExp(r'[-\/\\^$*+?.()|[\]{}]'), r'\\$&'))` part [escapes the literal part for use within regex](https://stackoverflow.com/a/3561711/3832970).

Or *whitespace boundaries*:

```
var regex = new RegExp("(?:^|\\s)(?:${keys.map((val) => val.replaceAll(new RegExp(r'[-\/\\^$*+?.()|[\]{}]'), r'\\$&')).join('|')})(?!\\S)", caseSensitive: false);
```

This results in a `(?:^|\s)(?:dev|soft|angular|java)(?!\S)` pattern where `(?:^|\s)` matches start of string or a whitespace char and `(?!\S)` requires the absense of a non-whitespace char immediately to the right of the current location.

See the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/Gjs56E/3).

Comment: Hi @Wiktor Stribiżew your solution is working as per my question. but it is not working with list of object ` var cc = contactsAll.where((i) => regex.hasMatch(i.displayName)).toList();
`

Comment: can you please help me with that

Comment: @arjunmore It should work. Please provide a reproducible sample to repro the issue. How do you initialize the `contactsAll` object?

Comment: my apologies i had intilaized list 2 times incorrectly. working as expected THANK YOU SO MUCH

Answer (score 0):

Without creating a function, you can use the `contains` method on your displayName like this :

```
    var cc = contactsAll
    .where((i) =>
        i.displayName.contains(RegExp('\\bdev\\b')) ||
        i.displayName.contains(RegExp('\\bsoft\\b')) ||
        i.displayName.contains(RegExp('\\bangular\\b')) ||
        i.displayName.contains(RegExp('\\bjava\\b')),)
    .toList();
```

Comment: Thank you @F Perroch